# configuration wampserver home router

Tags: wampserver

I can't access my wampserver from anther PC or cell phone. 
I think the problem from my wireless router because I reset my router for default setting. 
After resets I try to connect my wampserver but I found that I can't connect to the wampserver from others PC and cell phone.

How to configure wireless home router( my router is Dlink dsl) as localhost port?

Answer (score 0):

This is **probably** nothing to do with your router.

WAMPServer comes configured as a single seat developer tool, and therefore the Apache config is setup to only accept connections from the PC running WAMPServer (Apache) to protect new users from external hacking attempts.

The **Hammer to crack a Nut** solution is this :

```
left click wampmanager -> Put Online
```

This amends the Apache config `httpd.conf` file to allow connections from any IP address in the universe.

The **safer** solution is to edit the `httpd.conf` file yourself and add the following line to allow access just from your internal network. When you are using your phone to connect to your server, it will have to be connected to your WIFI.

Edit `htpd.conf` using the wampmanager menus

```
left click wampmanager -> Apache -> httpd.conf
```

Find these lines in that file

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
```

And add a line like this

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
Require ip 192.168.1
```

Where `192.168.1` is the subnet your router uses.

Note the use of only 3 of the 4 quartiles, this says allow any device on that subnet access to Apache i.e. anything cabled to your router of anything connected to your routers wifi.

If you want to be even more specific you can mention specific ip addresses like this

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require local
Require ip 192.168.1.20
Require ip 192.168.1.21
Require ip 192.168.1.22
```